# How can I embed a windows media player in my c#.net web application in visual studio 2005

Tags: c#

How can I embed a windows media player in my c#.net web application in visual studio 2005?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Windows Media Player detect and embed](http://blog.benpowell.co.uk/2007/09/windows-media-player-javascript-detect.html) JavaScript method that I put together. It is based off the SWFObject. There is also [an example](http://www.box.net/shared/3ddpad6hw0) available for download.